# React.Js Conditional Rendering: Code Explanation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I retrieved [this snippet](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/QKzAgB?editors=0010) from [React.js documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) that discusses conditional rendering.

From what I understand, the original state of `IsLoggedin` is the boolean value `false`. Hence, when called upon by the render function, as directed by the code, it should be passed as `props` to the `LogoutButton`. (If `isLoggedIn` is `false` (user is not logged in), then pass as props the state to function `LogoutButton` and display 'Logout' on the DOM). (If the statement is `true` (user is logged in) then pass as props the state to the `LoginButton` and display 'Login' to the screen. As you will notice when running the code on Codepen.io, that exactly the opposite holds.

For some reason, when the user is logged in (`isLoggedIn` is true), it displays the 'logout' on the DOM. Can someone explain this to me - why this is the case? Maybe, I am overlooking something.

Copy of the snippet:

```js
class LoginControl extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleLoginClick = this.handleLoginClick.bind(this);
    this.handleLogoutClick = this.handleLogoutClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {isLoggedIn: false};
  }

  handleLoginClick() {
    this.setState({isLoggedIn: true});
  }

  handleLogoutClick() {
    this.setState({isLoggedIn: false});
  }

  render() {
    const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
    let button;

    if (isLoggedIn) {
      button = <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />;
    } else {
      button = <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Greeting isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
        {button}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function UserGreeting(props) {
  return <h1>Welcome back!</h1>;
}

function GuestGreeting(props) {
  return <h1>Please sign up.</h1>;
}

function Greeting(props) {
  const isLoggedIn = props.isLoggedIn;
  if (isLoggedIn) {
    return <UserGreeting />;
  }
  return <GuestGreeting />;
}

function LoginButton(props) {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.onClick}>
      Login
    </button>
  );
}

function LogoutButton(props) {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.onClick}>
      Logout
    </button>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <LoginControl />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
button {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither `LogoutButton` nor `LoginButton` recieve any state as props. They recieve a handler function to change the state of `isLoggedIn`.

What `isLoggedIn` determines is which button gets assigned to the variable `let button`. When the user is already logged in (`isLoggedIn = true`), why would they still have the option to log in? The only action they can take at that point is to log out, and vice versa